# Looking for an Excel formula combining VLOOKUP and SEARCH functions

Tags: excel, search, excel-formula, vlookup, worksheet-function

I have a spreadsheet I am using for real estate where I want to be able to populate the name of a building based on an apartment's address.  I need to create a formula that searches for certain information on a cell (probably the building number) and, based on that, looks at a table with building numbers and corresponding names and returns the appropriate value.  I can't use a simple VLOOKUP based on the full address because, since they all contain apartment numbers, every address is unique.

[image: Screen shot of the Excel sheet]

I though about combining the search function with LOOKUP but that is not working for me so far.

Any thoughts on how to accomplish this?

Comment: Where is the building number in your address column D?

Comment: Thanks so much for the quick help!  I would have never gotten it.  Worked perfectly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please try:

```
=VLOOKUP(VALUE(LEFT(D4,FIND(" ",D4)-1)),W:X,2,0)
```

copied down to suit.

Good point spotted by @Jerry:

```
=VLOOKUP(VALUE(LEFT(TRIM(D8),FIND(" ",D8,2)-1)),W:X,2,0)
```

(though any leading space is not necessarily going to be removed by TRIM).

Comment: I would do a `TRIM` just in case as well, because there seems to be a space before the address, otherwise, that'd be what I'd use.